# Laravel 6 Error - Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert data into my database but this error shows up:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 
> Target class
>   [App\Http\Controllers\Master\Request] does not exist.

Though my Vendor Model and VendorController is in right directory.

**Here's my Vendor Model source code (\app\Model\Master):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Master;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vendor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vendors';

    public function user_modify()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'user_modified');
    }
}
```

**Here's my VendorController source code (\app\Http\Controllers\Master):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Master;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class VendorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view("vendor.index");
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view("vendor.create");
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new Vendor();

        $data->vendor_firstname = $request->first_name;
        $data->vendor_lastname = $request->last_name;
        $data->vendor_address = $request->address;
        $data->vendor_phone = $request->contact;
        $data->vendor_firstname = $request->first_name;
        $data->active = $request->vendor_status;
        $data->vendor_modified = Auth::user()->id;

        if($data->save()){
            return redirect()->route('vendor.index');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**And here's my route list:**

[image]

> What causes this error? And how do I fix it? tried running php artisan
>   config:cache and composer dump-autoload but still no luck..

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` place this in your controller, and i would recommend to make controllers and other stuff through cmd, do not copy and paste.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir thanks! added these two line of codes at the top of the VendorController..... use App\Model\Master\Vendor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Comment: welcome, Exactly, one is for request and another is your model name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` In your Controller File.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Master;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class VendorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view("vendor.index");
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view("vendor.create");
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = new Vendor();

        $data->vendor_firstname = $request->first_name;
        $data->vendor_lastname = $request->last_name;
        $data->vendor_address = $request->address;
        $data->vendor_phone = $request->contact;
        $data->vendor_firstname = $request->first_name;
        $data->active = $request->vendor_status;
        $data->vendor_modified = Auth::user()->id;

        if($data->save()){
            return redirect()->route('vendor.index');
        }else{
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
```